# Empty spaces in filtered list

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to return a list of all product IDs which contain 'sometag' in Shopify to power a theme section I'm building.

At first I was stuck by the limit of 50 products in a query (my catalogue is 600+ products), but by adding pagination to my for loop I have been able to return a filtered list from a collection containing all products to show only the tagged products I'm looking for.

However, despite the filtered list usually only containing around 1-5 items depending on tag, Shopify is still displaying the full pagination list for the entire product library - only every page is empty apart from the filtered items (which are usually on page 3 or 4 or something) - so it's not really removing the *filtered out* items, rather not displaying them and leaving their index spaces there empty.

Does anyone have any advice on how to trim out all the blank entries from the returned list and only display the filtered results?

```
{% paginate collections['somecollection'].products by 50 %}

    {% for product in collections['somecollection'].products %}
       {%- if product.tags contains 'sometag' -%}
          {{ product.id }}
       {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{{ paginate | default_pagination }}
{% endpaginate %}
```

**EDIT: Shopify tell me this is 'expected behavior'** so I guess I need to create some mini app or use JS or something.

> Because Liquid pagination happens server-side, it will always be based on the actual size of the collection, not on a sorted subset created for front end display.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could create a list using the tag as condition

Comment: @FabioFilippi Wouldn't I have the same issue with the limit of 50 products per query? I mean, I agree with your suggestion - but what array would I use to query based on a tag? I thought using a collection of all products was basically my only choice here?

Comment: You would still need the pagination but it would work out of the box. Instead of `collections['somecollection']` you use your `'sometag'` new collection and remove the `if` condition.
Sorry I improperly used the word 'list' in my previous comment, I meant a collection

Comment: @FabioFilippi Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, that could work in theory but would involve creating a LOT of collections in my case... and I'm actually presenting a slightly simplified version of what I'm ultimately trying to do here. I need to resolve this 'empty spaces' issue with pagination and/or find a way to return a clean list of filtered items from a for loop querying all products. Thanks though!

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. Because shopify will only give up to 50 products. You cannot paginate in any other way. The only possible solution is to use an app and create a custom endpoint and populate the list with an ajax call.